# Sublime Text 2 >IndentationError<

Tags: python, python-2.7, sublimetext2, indentation

I have a problem with sublime text 2. 
When I write some python scripts correctly at sublime text I always face on with this problem
***"IndentationError: unexpected indent"***
after a while I found, the problem is causing by sublime text. I tried other editors and corrected but sublime text didnt work correctly.

The main problem is, sublime text is adding extra tab to my line and that affects my script works. I couldnt find the reason. hope somebody help me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Without code we can't help you.

Comment: Screenshots, code? Anything? Give us something, we aren't psychic

Comment: Maybe you are using spaces *and* tabs combined, for indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings

Change it to this:

```
{
    "tab_size": 4,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. it did work!